# Are any laws of the synagogue D’oraita?

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, synagogue, architecture-design, deorayta

There are certain Halacha parameters for a synagogue (its sanctity, to an extent its design and architecture etc.). I am confused as to whether all of these are Derabbanan, or if any are D’oraita, and if so which? Obviously there aren’t exactly modern “synagogues” per se in the Bible, but are any Torah laws still relevant to Hilchos Beit Haknesset?

Comment: According to Rav Moshe Feinstein the mechitza is deorysa

Comment: Based on the argument of whether a beit kneset is considered like the beit hamikdash (מקדש מעט) — there are various dinim that could be classified as doraita

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Chofetz Chaim in Sefer Chofetz Chaim where he lists the positive commandments clearly states in Positive Mitzva number 7 that current day shuls and batei Mirash have the same laws of the temple as a mikdash maat.:

וְכָל זֶה אֲפִלּוּ (ז) שֶׁלֹּא בְּבֵית הַמִדְרָשׁ, אֲבָל אִם מְדַבֵּר לָשׁוֹן הָרָע וּרְכִילוּת בְּבֵית הַמִדְרָשׁ אוֹ בְּבֵית הַכְּנֶסֶת, עוֹבֵר עוֹד עַל מִצְוַת עֲשֵׂה (ויקרא י"ט ל'): "וּמִקְדָּשִׁי תִּירָאוּ" וּבֵית הַמִדְרָשׁ שֶׁלָּנוּ גַּם כֵּן בִּכְלַל מִקְדָּשׁ הוּא, כְּמוֹ שֶׁמְבֹאָר בַּפּוֹסְקִים, וְנִצְטַוֵּינוּ בְּזֶה הַפָּסוּק לִירֹא, מְמִי שֶׁשּׁוֹכֵן בּוֹ, וְלָכֵן אֵין מְחַשְּׁבִין בּוֹ חֶשְׁבּוֹנוֹת, כִּי אִם שֶׁל מִצְוָה, כְּגוֹן קֻפָּה שֶׁל צְדָקָה וְכַדּוֹמֶה, וְכָל שֶׁכֵּן דְּאָסוּר בָּהֶם שְׂחוֹק וְהִתּוּל וְשִׂיחָה בְּטֵלָה, וְלֹא מוֹעִיל בָּזֶה שׁוּם תְּנַאי, כַּמְבֹאָר בְּשֻׁלְחָן עָרוּךְ אֹרַח חַיִּים (בסימן קנ"א סעיף י"א).